# Web Api - Initialize() is not being called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using web api 2, and have a controller that inherits from another controller that overrides the Initialize() method of ApiController.

So:

```
public class ControllerA : Controller B
```

then:

```
public class ControllerB : ApiController
{  
   protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var httpContext = GetHttpContext(controllerContext.Request);
        // Do some stuff
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    }
 }
```

But when I debug, the breakpoint on initialize is never hit. Other breakpoints hit, but not on this method. Any ideas?

Comment: `Controller B` should probably be one word, but I doubt that's what's causing it - probably a typo.

Comment: Why not simply have a `constructor` instead of having a `Initialize`-method? The constructor *has* to be called.

Comment: Does it get called if you make request to ControllerB?

Comment: I know in ASP.Net, some of the overrides in global.asax won't hit the breakpoints as it's too early in the process.  Have you tried writing to the debug console in Visual Studio to see if it's actually running, but just not hitting the breakpoint?

Comment: @Orphid Yea that is a typo - I added my initialize to controllerA and directly inherited from ApiController and it still wont hit. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Like @diemaus mentioned, try adding the initialization code to the constructor or call the 'intialize' method from the constructor

Comment: @Opeoluwa .. how that helps? you are not supposed to call this method directly.

Comment: Can you post the exact name of the controller?.. `controllerA`/`controllerB` is not a valid controller name.

Answer (score 0):

`Initialize` method is not like a constructor when the controller is called. 
It should be called manually to reinitialize my controller context to another class.